# SVG SMIL or RequestAnimationFrame animation

Tags: performance, svg, svg-animate, smil

I have 2 options of animating a SVG shape transform attribute. The first one is trough SMIL. The downside is a less browser support. The second one is trough JavaScript, I get a better browser support but add complexity.

Are there any performance reports or studies made to backout one or the other? Are SMIL animations done on a different UI threat?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sarah Drasner wrote a wonderful guest post about this on CSS Tricks: [Weighing SVG Animation Techniques (with Benchmarks)](https://css-tricks.com/weighing-svg-animation-techniques-benchmarks/). It's definitely worth to take a look at it.

Comment: If the answer to OP's question can be found in your link, it is best to include the relevant information in your answer. Otherwise, your response is more of a comment.